# ReactJS values of Const on div

Tags: javascript, java, html, reactjs, rest

I'm new on react and have a simple application as this:

[image]

My purpose for this app it's to consume an ***Spring Boot REST Service*** and print the data **json** on my react app.

I achieve this following this tutorial: https://github.com/marmelab/restful.js/tree/master

But now I'm stuck on a simple problem, *don't know how to print the values on a html tag*, this is an example of my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import request from 'request';
import restful, { requestBackend } from 'restful.js';

const api = restful('http://someUrl/v1/mobile', requestBackend(request));
const totals = api.one('statusOrders',1); //organizationID = 1

totals.get().then((response) => {
    const requestBody = response.body();
    const totalsOrders = requestBody.data(); /*Need to print this on the <div>**/
})

class RestGps extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="container">
                <p>Hello World</p>
                //Here I want to print the values.
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default RestGps
```

The ***const*** totalsOrders has the values of the request, the request structure it's like this:

```
{
  "remissionOk": 109,
  "remissionAlert": 5,
  "remissionError": 17,
  "remissionOutOfTime": 82
}
```

¿Can someone please tell me how can I print this **totalsOrders** on my html as my text "Hello World"? Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to change some things around.

1. Your `totalOrders` object needs to be within the scope of your `RestGps` class.
2. You aren't using `states`, which can cause a lot of weird behaviour!

I suggest doing the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import request from 'request';
import restful, { requestBackend } from 'restful.js';

const api = restful('http://someUrl/v1/mobile', requestBackend(request));
const totals = api.one('statusOrders',1); //organizationID = 1

class RestGps extends React.Component {

    state = { text: "loading ..." };

    componentDidMount = () => {
        totals.get().then((response) => {
            const requestBody = response.body();
            const totalsOrders = requestBody.data(); // assuming this is object
            this.setState({ text: JSON.stringify(totalsOrders) });
        })
    }

    render = () => {
        return(
           <div className="container">
                 <p>{this.state.text}</p>
                //Here I want to print the values.
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default RestGps
```

### Why are using states?

Well. Initially, your component won't have any data to show. This is because `get` takes time to fetch remote resources.

So what will tell react to re-render your component, to show the text once the resource gets loaded? Nothing! This is why you need to use states.

### What is `componentDidMount`?

`componentDidMount` is a function part of the react lifecycle. It is called when the component initially gets rendered. When it renders, you want to fetch the resource, then update our state.

### How do we pass the string into the paragraph element?

This is simple, you can just reference your state in the `render` function, using `this.state.text`, then add it as a text node in `<p>`

Comment: Thanks for the replay @JClassic marks me the error: expecting new line or semicolon on the **const initialState** and **const state**

Comment: just remove `const` from both those lines

Comment: Thanks, applying your changes works great and your explication it's really useful.

Comment: No problem! Glad everything worked out :^) I apologize for some syntax errors, as I haven't been programming in js for a while

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of life cycle methods.

```
class RestGps extends React.Component {

    state = {
      totalsOrders : null,
    };

    componentDidMount() {
      const api = restful('http://someUrl/v1/mobile', requestBackend(request));
      const totals = api.one('statusOrders',1); //organizationID = 1

    totals.get().then((response) => {
    const requestBody = response.body();
    const totalsOrders = requestBody.data(); /*Need to print this on the <div>**/
    this.setState({totalsOrders: totalsOrders });
})
    }

    render(){
        const {totalsOrders} = this.state;
        return(
             <div className="container">
                <p>Hello World</p>
            totalsOrders.map(item => {
                {item}
            }); 
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```